# Создание таблицы через document.write

Tags: javascript

Сразу говорю - другие варианты кроме document.write не подходят.
Задание:
Добавьте в документ код JavaScript так, чтобы в окне браузера была выведена таблица степеней двойки вида:
Таблица из 6 строк. В первой ячейке 2 в степени, во второй ячейке результат.

Для этого в сценарии используйте метод write(…) объекта document для формирования содержимого страницы. На каждой итерации цикла for сформируйте очередную строку таблицы, в первую ячейку которой заносится соответствующая степень двойки, а во вторую результат ее возведения в указанную степень. Для выполнения этого действия используется встроенный объект Math и его метод pow(…), возводящий первый параметр в степень, заданную вторым параметром. Обратите внимание, что метод write(…) может вызываться с любым количеством фактических параметров. Результатом его работы в любом случае является вывод в документ строки, полученной конкатенацией всех параметров, переданных в метод.

**Я не могу приложить свой код** потому что я понятия не имею реально ли вообще это реализовать. Я без проблем могу написать через createElement, но эти темы еще не проходили и такое не прокатит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
document.write('<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center">');
for(var i=2; i<8; i++) {
    document.write('<tr><td style="width: 30px">2 <sup>'+i+'</sup></td><td style="width: 30px">'+Math.pow(2,i)+'</td></tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать не слишком ли это сложно.

Comment: @diraria, стили я добавил просто для красоты. по заданию они не нужны

Comment: @websnap, если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте

Comment: мне-то понятно, но это задание для студентки. решение должно более-менее соответствовать тому уровню знаний, который им дают.

Comment: @websnap, ну, стили уберите из тегов, чтобы не смущать студентку.